# How to add separate google analytics for a subdomain

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, subdomain, analytics

I have a site which has bee successfully using google analytics for some time.  I have a new project which I have added as a subdomain. Lets call it: **newproject.mydomain.com**

I want to add google analytics to  **newproject.mydomain.com** without effecting the original analytics for **www.mydomain.com**.

As I would like this to have a separate tracking code and not interact in anyway with the existing analytics my first thought is to setup a new property under the same account.

I set the property url to: newproject.subdomain.com but when I look at the generated js tracking code it contains the following line, which indicates it is pointed at the domain root not the subdomain.

```
ga('create', 'UA-********-2', 'mydomain.com');
```

When I add the code to the subdomain pages and check the status it says:

*Status: Tracking Not Installed
Last checked: 12-Oct-2013 03:28:12 PDT
The Google Analytics tracking code has not been detected on your website's home page. For Analytics to function, you or your web administrator must add the code to each page of your website.*

So obviously it is expecting the code to be in the index of the main site not the subdomain, but I am not sure how to go about achieving my goal, or even if I am on the right track, so any help will be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

```
ga('create', 'UA-********-2', 'mydomain.com');
```

automatically tracks data from all subdomains, so maybe is something wrong with your implementation.

If you're using Google Chrome try installing [Google Tag Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk) extension which can give you useful information about tags on your page and also displays warnings if something's wrong.